# Are "Monster Musume no Iru Nichijou" (the anime) and "MonMusu Quest" (the VN) related?

Tags: discussion, tags

A few months ago, the tag [monmusu-quest](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monmusu-quest) was created. This appears to be for [the VN "MonMusu Quest"](https://vndb.org/v5657). Just now, I created the tag [monmusu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monmusu) for the anime [Monster Musume no Iru Nichijou](http://myanimelist.net/anime/30307/Monster_Musume_no_Iru_Nichijou) (because the full title was longer than 25 characters, and this is the standard abbreviation).

Are these two things in any way related? Should they share the same tag?

If not, somebody who knows stuff about these two series should put a bit of disambiguating information in the tag wiki excerpts for future reference.

(I would research this myself, but, you know, [spiders](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/25893/).)

Comment: I haven't played monmuse quest, but I believe they are unrelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two titles are unrelated.

- *Monmusu Quest* is set in a medieval setting, and the hero sets out on an adventure with the ideal of having monster girl and human coexist together peacefully. However, not all monster girls can be reasoned with, so he has to fight against quite a number of them on his adventure.
- *Monster Musume no Iru Nichijou* is set in present day, about the life of a man with monster girls on cultural exchange.

Comment: Awesome. I added a short bit to each of the tag wiki excerpts.